# How to render dynamically created HTML string into razor view in Asp.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have written html helper method as below

```
 public static class CustomHtmlHelper
{
    public static HtmlString SetMenuRespectiveWithRoles(this IHtmlHelper html, HttpContext context)
    {
        StringBuilder menu = new StringBuilder();
        string menuLink = string.Format("<a asp-area='{0}' asp-controller='{1}' asp-action='{2}'>{3}</a></li>", "AreaName", "ControllerName", "ActionName", "Menu Name");
        return new HtmlString(menu.ToString());
    }
}
```

And calling it from layout as -

```
 @Html.SetMenuRespectiveWithRoles(Context)
```

It renders on browser as -

```
<a asp-area="AreaName" asp-controller="ControllerName" asp-action="ActionName">MenuName</a>
```

I was expecting that it will render as

```
<a href="AreaName/ControllerName/ActionName">MenuName</a>
```

I don't want to create html tag using `TagHelpers` class.

Can you please guide how can we render dynamically created string in .net core razor page?

Comment: Why not use the built-in `IHtmlHelper.ActionLink` method? You're trying to write your own without any special requirement which cannot be fulfilled by the built-in method.

Comment: I have given just one line code to make the question shorter. Actually I have other logic into it where I am creating few more html controls as well

Comment: so you can use the `IHtmlHelper.ActionLink` inside your method (kind of a wrapper). It's just easy like that.

Comment: `I don't want to create html tag using TagHelpers class` do you mean that you do not want to manually create html tag with expected html attributes in your helper method?

Comment: yes @FeiHan. I am thinking there must be some way in .net core where we can we can render html code. Like we Html.Raw or MvcHtmlString in MVC